# What is a normal file copy speed for SSD?

Tags: windows-7, performance, ssd

I am copying a folder (320 items, 1.9GB) on an SSD to a different location on the same SSD and getting a transfer rate of 5MB/s.

Is this to be expected? Simultaneous reading and writing to the same drive will slow things down, but still - I would guess this rate is slow.

I get these values from HDTune benchmark:

(Read)

Transfer rate: min=12.6 avg=16.4 max=16.8 MB/s

Access time: .300ms

Burst rate: 17.9MB/s

Comment: How full is the drive?

Comment: What SSD is it? Also, for context, what sort of transfer speeds to you get copying the same folder to/from a different drive (if you have another drive)?

Comment: It is very full: 6GB free of a 128GB drive.

Comment: I don't have another internal drive. the SSD shows up as "Samsung SSD RBX Series 128GB M ATA Device" in device manager.

Comment: Not exactly the fastest according to this  http://www.harddrivebenchmark.net/hdd_lookup.php?cpu=SAMSUNG+SSD+RBX+Series+128GB+M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you think all SSD's are equal (or near equal) which is not true. See, for example [these benchmarks](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/windows-7-ssd-trim,2705-15.html)

Also the speed is not just dependent on the SSD.

But no, I would not consider 5MB/s to be particularly fast.

For example, the last real copy I did that I can remember (around 2GB and 10,000 files) was reported by Windows as around 40MB/s. (This is on an Intel SSDSA2M080G2GC SSD which is over a year old and hence may not be particularly fast)

```
HD Tune: INTEL SSDSA2M080G2GC Benchmark

Transfer Rate Minimum : 88.8 MB/sec
Transfer Rate Maximum : 221.3 MB/sec
Transfer Rate Average : 210.0 MB/sec
Access Time           : 0.1 ms
Burst Rate            : 144.8 MB/sec
CPU Usage             : -1.0%
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your SSD garbage collector is full and overloaded. Transfers to SSD tends to be better if you put your SSD in idle for some time. Howerver you could try a firmware upgrade for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the real effective transfer speed of you SSD/HDD with [HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com) or [HDtach](http://www.simplisoftware.com/Public/index.php?request=HdTach).